# Defining Unique Attribute causes a crash when storing data more than once

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have a SwiftData Model, when I use the @Attribute macro on 'id', I get a crash when attempting to store data for the second time.  It is my understanding that SwiftData is supposed to 'upsert' unique fields if the data already exists?

The debugger output is not useful at all.

Errors

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x23c8c18f4)

#0  0x000000023c8c18f4 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol3765 ()
```

User Model

```
@Model
class  User: Codable, Identifiable {

@Attribute(.unique)
var id: UUID
var name: String

init(id: UUID, name: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, name
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
}


required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
}
}
```

Comment: The problem might be related to having the model conforming to `Codable`. It looks like `Codable` and `@Model` isn't a good combination. Use a separate struct for `Codable` instead.

Comment: If you don't think this is the reason then post a reproducible example.

Comment: Almost certain to be the solution.  After much reading reached the same conclusion! Now to test.   Thanks for pointing in the right direction..